# Checking if string contains substring in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

I was wondering if there is a way to look for a `substring` in a `char*` array.

I can't seem to find an equivalent of `Contains()` from `Java` for `C`

For example:

`char *buff = "this is a test string. The string contains random text.";`

suppose I input the `substring` to compare to `buff` and see how many times is `substring` found in `buff`.

I am able to find the first occurrence but having issues with multiple occurrences. Can someone assist me?

Comment: So what exactly you don't understand then? The obvious thing is to restart the search after the first position you have found. If you don't know to do that it is time to revise (1) how arrays and strings work in C, (2) how iteration statements work in C.

Comment: Hi all, suppose I have a `char* random` with values `ABCDSDGHFG` and I want to extract a substring based on 2 index values, how would I retrieve that?


Basically something similar to java that would do the following:

`substring(2, 5)`

Answer (score 3):

There is a standard C library function called `strstr` which does substring searches:

```
#include <string.h>

char *strstr(const char *haystack, const char *needle);

The strstr() function finds the first occurrence of the substring needle
in the string haystack.  The terminating null bytes ('\0') are not compared.
```

Comment: how to find multiple occurrence?

Comment: Well, you can use the start of the first substring match and the length of the substring itself to calculate a new starting point for a subsequent substring search. Or, if the substring can match itself, simply start a new search one character after the last result.

Comment: Does `Contains` return multiple occurrences in Java then?

Comment: Hi all, suppose I have a `char* random` with values `ABCDSDGHFG` and I want to extract a substring based on 2 index values, how would I retrieve that?


Basically something similar to java that would do the following:

`substring(2, 5)`

Comment: @isedev yes you are correct about the Contains method

Answer (score 1):

Such a function is named `strstr` and declared in header `<string.h>`

From the C Standard

7.23.5.7 The strstr function
Synopsis
1

```
#include <string.h>
char *strstr(const char *s1, const char *s2);
```

Description
2 The strstr function locates the first occurrence in the string pointed to by s1 of the sequence of characters (excluding the terminating null character) in the string pointed to by s2.

Returns
3 The strstr function returns a pointer to the located string, or a null pointer if the string is not found. If s2 points to a string with zero length, the function returns s1.