# Function to search a string inside of string C

Tags: c, string, function

Is there a function to search a string inside of string?
For example: String: "Hello". And I want to check if the string "ell" is inside the string "Hello".

Comment: [`strstr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr)

Comment: try [`strstr()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strstr)

Comment: A [good standard string function reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte) should help.

Comment: Ah.. I am probably too late with all ya guys to suggest `strstr`?

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26231388/checking-if-string-contains-substring-in-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about `strstr()`?

```
char *strstr(const char *haystack, const char *needle);
```

for your example, just do the following:

```
char *ocurrence_str = strstr("Hello", "ell");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use library `strstr()` function, which is returns pointer to the first occurrence of the string in a given string.

Read [man](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strstr.3.html) page of strstr function for more information.

Comment: Note: C has no builtin functions! The standard library is not builtin.